# how to pass some getElementById inside onclick

Tags: javascript, input, onclick, submit, getelementbyid

I have this:

```
<div id="atc_images"></div>
<textarea id="img" style="display:none" rows="30" cols="30" name="cur_image"></textarea> 

<input name="invia" type="submit" value="Invia" onclick="document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = getElementById('atc_images').innerHTML";>
```

So I send to `submit.php` the content that will be generating inside `<div id="atc_images"></div>`

How can I pass multiple `getElementById` all at one time when `<input type="submit"..>` is clicked?

I want something like this:

```
<input name="invia" type="submit" value="Invia" onclick="document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = getElementById('atc_images').innerHTML && document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = getElementById('title_inside_another_div').innerHTML";>
```

Comment: you can't `getElementById` only selects the first instance of the element with the corresponding ID, i suggest you use `document.getElementsByClassName("classname")` and loop through it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just add both statements into the onclick parameter, separated by a semi-colon, just as you would in a SCRIPT block. Remember to use `document.getElementById`, not just `getElementById`.

```
<input name="invia" type="submit" value="Invia" onclick="document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = document.getElementById('atc_images').innerHTML; document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = document.getElementById('title_inside_another_div').innerHTML";>
```

Comment: perfect..so i can add more separated by a semi-colon..or is not work good..i need pass about 3 or 4 document.getElementById

Comment: You can add as many as you like, but it might be a better idea to create a separate function that does all of that, and just call the function from the onclick parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a semi-colon instead of '&&'

Answer (score 1):

IDs need to be unique for elements, thus it's best to name the elements what you want to send via its class name. Then use document.getElementsByClassName("class").

Also make sure your target browser works with it, nothing IE 8 or below works: http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname